# How to deal with an immature colleague without being a "snitch"

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, complaint

In October i returned to my old job after having a two year hiatus as a teacher during corona. I have some create colleagues and a good manager, but there is a small issue, our department (Applications) shares an office with a other department (Onsite support).

The head of the department is actually barely on location due to a large project on located on the other side of the country (he is in charge of all on site support for four departments). And his "second in command" in charge of our location for that department had a stroke at the end of the last year and is still recovering. Due to some hiring issues they are understaffed and the "senior" of the department is now a 19 year old who just graduated... he's a generally speaking good kid and he knows his stuff but there have been issues, namely:

- Their department has a walk in time between 13:00 and 15:30 (for basic issues, high priority is between 9:00 and 16:00) but he
  often runs late (usually 15 minutes but sometimes up to an hour) because they take their big break just before.
- He had his headset on listening to music during walk in hours, not
  even noticing people at the desk...so i walk in to greet em even
  though it's not even my department.
- When not wearing his headset his music is rather loud, and he has a
  knack of singing along (most colleague from my department already spends most of their
  time working from home or in a conference room where it is quite).
- He is a bit of a bad influence on the temp worker, having shootouts
  with rubber bands that tend to reach our side of the office
  (sometimes even hitting our screens).
- Although we have an hour break a day he uses that up + several smoke
  breaks that last a bit to long to be considered just smoke breaks if
  you ask me.

**And i'm wondering how to best handle this without being a snitch...** generally speaking we have a very nice office environment but now that he has almost no oversight he is behaving like a kid and it's starting to annoy everybody but none of us want to make a big fuss about it because it's just a little thing here and there...but the little things are adding up.

My main concern is that the General IT department has been getting complaints, which includes both the department i am in and theirs because people think "IT = IT". Today a lady from HR came by for support, told her they were on a smoke break and i'd relay her request as soon as they were back...but that smoke break lasted over 45 minutes and when they came back they were like "Well tell her to comeback and ask in person or comeback tomorrow"... although it wasn't my job i pass her her on my way to my car so i told her she could go by. But she was kinda ticked of she had to wait for 45 minutes because of a smoke break.... and seeing she kinda knew about it from me i expect a lot of drama when they arrive at work tomorrow because after i spoke with her she went to them to ask them what that long smoke break is about.

There were already several complaints filled against them, but they weasel themselves out with excuses and their manager currently doesn't have the oversight/time to deal with it properly and believes them on their word. And the colleagues from my department have gone to start working more form home/in the conference rooms...but it's against my principles to be run out of my own bloody office.

I tried talking to them directly, but they bluntly tell me it's one of my business because i am not their manager or even part of their department. And i don't want to make a to big a fuss about it seeing i just came back.

I think  his behavior is part due to his age, part due to his lack of oversight and part due to the fact that his father is a manager of a other department in the company.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yet our department suffers under it :| But damn asking for advice is a sin here so it seems... can't even delete the question.

Comment: You understand that by covering him when he has “customers” you endorse his behavior?

Comment: _"There were already several complaints filled against them, but they weasel themselves out with excuses and their manager currently doesn't have the oversight/time to deal with it properly and believes them on their word."_ So even if you were to snitch, what are you expecting to be able to to differently than is already being done?

Comment: @A.bakker: "Don't do it" is not the same as "You should have never asked this question". It's a valid answer your problem (note the distinction between valid and correct - I am not commenting on correctness, only on applicability).

Comment: Could you look back at all before '… he knows his stuff but there have been issues…' and consider reducing it by at very least half, to avoid TL;DR Comments?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere o the advice is not the thing that annoys me, the downvotes without clarification is the thing that is rather annoying.

Comment: @Flater i'm not disagreeing with the answer, but the as i said in the other comment, the downvotes without clarification... if you want something to improve, give feedback :|

Comment: In general, one of the things we learn as we get older is to drop the "being a snitch" mentality. Either something is directly a problem for you within your job description or is a serious
 problem for the company -- in which case you are justified in asking management to help solve it -- or it isn't. And if it isn't, then it simply isn't your responsibility to try to fix it.

Answer (score 14):

#### You don't

Stop doing their job (welcoming people, etc.), and it will catch up to them.

Telling them to stop bothering you is just basic office stuff.  If that keeps you from getting your work done then escalate it to your boss.  How they spend their time doesn't affect your work, so just let it go.

Comment: The problem is the reputation part, when people file complaints, it's against IT and not their specific department. And sadly when it comes to performance reviews those complaints have en effect in the statistics :|

Comment: @A.bakker: As a manager I would be hard-pressed to consider "I don't like the reputation impact on me" as a valid workplace complaint just because you sometimes fly under the same banner as someone who is getting complaints levied against them. Your question is accounting for how you are perceived; and making reputation claims IMHO either suggests that you have the wrong goal here, or that you're going to be perceived negatively for appearing to have the wrong goal. As an employee, you should only be commenting on getting your work done and what impedes that.

Comment: @A.bakker it sounds like in that case you may want to fix the complaint process.  Either have it have a separate category for department or replace the option for IT with two (or more) specific options for your respective departments.  Which at that point you and your department can easily file their own complaints about the other department too.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with Tiger Guy's answer and it is the standard recommend course of action.  However, there is an alternative approach I have seen done that when it works it is amazing:

### Mentoring

The person in question that is causing the problems is 19 years old, and has yet to learn how to behave properly at a job.  If they are fired it will not teach them how to work, but how to not get fired, and they will become someone else's problem.

The way to fix this is the person needs someone to take on the role as their mentor. Becoming a mentor is a slow process.  The mentor has to gain their respect so that when the mentor tells them how to act they will listen and take the advice to heart.  The quote: *People don't care how much you know until they know how much you care - Theodore Roosevelt* is at work here. This involves getting to know them, learn about their hobbies, their life, show interest, and care for them.  One of the key things is finding common ground or being able to relate to them.

Normally at this point I would recommend that you think about becoming their mentor.  Unfortunately this approach likely has little chance of working for you since you have already attempted to reprimand them directly and so their opinion and view of you has already formed.  You can still attempt this if you feel up for one heck of a challenge.

In my own personal experience people from the older generations mentoring me has had a huge positive impact on how I act.  I know of others who they did not ask for a mentor, but a mentor found them and invested their time and resources (and quite considerable amounts of both) into them and helped them move their life and work in a much better direction.